# mysqli_query() doesn't insert into table

Tags: php, mysql

Have no idea why it won't insert

```
$name = 'tom';
    $email = 'swag';
    $number = 123;

mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `table` (`name`, `email`, 
`number`) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$number')");
```

This is just a test to see why it won't insert, i have set the connection up and there are no errors being thrown.

Comment: Do you have a valid connection? Have you attempted ***any*** debugging?!

Comment: Are you seeing any errors at all? Anything in the logs? Have you made a connection?

Comment: And can you say SQL-Injection?  Definitely read up before getting too deep.

Comment: Please can't you see this is a test if this is a real world application I would sanitize the data.

Comment: You need to learn how to debug, turn on error mode thats it

Comment: @Aron: If your real-world scenario uses proper query parameterization then this isn't really a valid test, is it?  The "real" code would be very different.

Comment: "why it won't insert" is pointless since you don't have actually CHECK for any reasons why. `$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con))` is the LEAST you should have

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation for `mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), it returns `FALSE` on failure and `TRUE` on successful inserts.

So first, check its return value to see if it thinks it failed or succeeded. It probably thinks it failed, in which case, use `mysqli_error()` to get a string description of the error.